# PHP - backup file before updating it

Tags: php, file, updates

I created a function to get the latest version of some file from github and update the local one. Here is the code:

```
$remoteFile = $remote; // File from github.
$localFile = $local; // File to be updated (/app/lib/example.php).

// If file exists, it must be copied to a backup (.bak) version.
if (file_exists($localFile)) {
    rename($localFile, $localFile.'.bak');
}

$newFile = fopen($localFile, 'w');
fwrite($newFile, file_get_contents($remoteFile));
fclose($newFile);
```

The problem is that this code updates the file before renaming it. In other words, the current and the backup files will have the same updated code.
Anybody knows why?

Comment: This seems rather roundabout. Why not just use git to pull the file(s)?

Comment: Because this function runs within a framework and everytime I update the code in github, every installation should get the updated files

Comment: So cron a git pull?

Comment: Make sure the code doesn't run twice. This is the most reasonable explanation for the behaviour you described, I think.

Comment: And is it possible to backup files using this workaround?

Comment: @axiac I'm gonna check it

Comment: You don't need to backup files pulled from git, if you need an older copy, you just checkout an older copy. That's kinda the whole point of git.

Comment: Tried your code and it works fine. As @axiac said, you probably get the code to run twice.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that this framework will might be used for people tat knows nothing about git, thats why i need to backup files the most intuitive and clearer way

Comment: @AlinPurcaru really? Could you confirm that the backup file has a different content from the updated one?

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1270 Apr 26 15:58 local.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9929 Apr 26 15:57 local.txt.bak :-)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunatelly, It does not run for me :/

Comment: It must be some server config

Comment: You should try to isolate your scenario to determine if it's the code or some OS issue. Add to the question what you actually have in `$remote` and `$local`, and the way you are running the PHP code. I ran it from command line, through the php executable.